# command line tool to manage multiple displays?

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, display

Sorry for this post being such a mess but I'm having quite the problem with booting into blinking cursor, I've tried a myriad of things with no success. My suspicion is as following:
I just set up my Ubuntu installation the day before. To manage multiple displays I used a command line tool, NOT xrandr. The name was like yasper or so, like a real name. It had the argument --list to list all monitors. I kind of forced it by using a combination of this tool and the system monitor management to get a combination of cloning and extending with my 3 monitors. I bet this is what is causing my blank screen. And I CAN'T find the name of this tool anymore (google, askubuntu, nothing..). Can anyone help?

Comment: Tried looking through your `.bash_history` file?

Comment: Thanks, that helped me find the tool! The name is "disper". Couldn't resolve my issue, but thanks.